# Apply User-Defined Function to Specific Dataframe Columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have seen the question here [R apply user define function on data frame columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939461/r-apply-user-define-function-on-data-frame-columns) but mine is a little different...

I would like to pass specific columns of my dataframe to a function, then return the result of that function to a new column of my dataframe.

Basically, I have a dataframe like this:

```
df.latitude1
df.longitude1
df.latitude2
df.longitude2
```

Then I have a method `getDistance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)` and I would like to return the result of that computation into a new column in my dataframe called `distance`.

### Update

```
> asn$geoDistance <- distHaversine(asn[,c("homeLocationGeoLat", "homeLocationGeoLng")], dat[,c("hostLocationGeoLat", "hostLocationGeoLng")])
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : latitude < -90
> asn$homeLocationGeoLat[asn$homeLocationGeoLat < -90]
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [40] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [79] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[118] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[157] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[196] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[235] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[274] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[313] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[352] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[391] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[430] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[469] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[508] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[547] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> asn$hostLocationGeoLat[asn$hostLocationGeoLat < -90]
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [40] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [79] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[118] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[157] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[196] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[235] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[274] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[313] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[352] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[391] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[430] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[469] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[508] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[547] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[586] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[625] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[664] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[703] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> newDf <- asn[, c('durationDays', 'homeLocationGeoLat', 'homeLocationGeoLng', 'hostLocationGeoLat', 'hostLocationGeoLng')]
> dput(head(newDf))
structure(list(durationDays = c(0, 0, 180, 0, 365, 0), homeLocationGeoLat = c(-23.5489433, 
1.2800945, 12.9715987, 25.7889689, 49.3063689, 25.271139), homeLocationGeoLng = c(-46.6388182, 
103.8509491, 77.5945627, -80.2264393, 8.6427693, 55.307485), 
    hostLocationGeoLat = c(37.4418834, 49.2774456, 52.3905689, 
    49.3063689, 53.3498053, 37.4418834), hostLocationGeoLng = c(-122.1430195, 
    7.1118995, 13.0644729, 8.6427693, -6.2603097, -122.1430195
    )), .Names = c("durationDays", "homeLocationGeoLat", "homeLocationGeoLng", 
"hostLocationGeoLat", "hostLocationGeoLng"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use a vectorized function and compute the distances for all pairs of points at the same time. For instance, you could use the `distHaversine` function from the `geosphere` package to do the calculation in one shot:

```
# 10000 points
set.seed(144)
dat <- data.frame(lat1=runif(10000, 10, 20), lng1=runif(10000, 10, 20),
                  lat2=runif(10000, 10, 20), lng2=runif(10000, 10, 20))

# Get all distances
library(geosphere)
dat$distance <- distHaversine(dat[,c("lng1", "lat1")], dat[,c("lng2", "lat2")])
head(dat$distance)
# [1] 293912.3 332583.2 870767.8 167362.9 371920.6 659368.1
```

If you were going to use a function from the `apply` family, you would probably loop through the rows of your data frame, computing the distances one at a time. While this will give the same answer, it will be much slower:

```
all.equal(distHaversine(dat[,c("lng1", "lat1")], dat[,c("lng2", "lat2")]),
          apply(dat, 1, function(x) distHaversine(x[c("lng1", "lat1")], x[c("lng2", "lat2")])))
# [1] TRUE
system.time(distHaversine(dat[,c("lng1", "lat1")], dat[,c("lng2", "lat2")]))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.005   0.001   0.008 
system.time(apply(dat, 1, function(x) distHaversine(x[c("lng1", "lat1")], x[c("lng2", "lat2")])))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.887   0.007   0.895
```

The reason for the 100x slowdown is that you can't take advantage of vectorization if you perform the distance computation one row at a time.